# How to initialize a (complex?) struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Let's define this struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
    char * firstString;
    char * secondString;
};
```

I'm trying to initialize a struct like this:

```
MyStruct s = {4, 5, {'a', 'b', 'c'}, "abc"};
```

But it's not working. Is there any way to do it? (the firstString is required not to have '\0' at the end)

Comment: Pointers are **NOT** arrays. Use an array!

Comment: Why not MyStruct s = {4, 5, "abc", "abc"};? There's no real semantic difference; you have to store the fact that firstString has only 3 characters somewhere anyway, and a \0 could appear in memory after the c in your version (if it worked).

Comment: You might want to accept answers to questions that you've asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your requirement is to not have a null terminator at the end, you have to use an array for `firstString`:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
    char firstString[3];
    char * secondString;
};
```

Then you can initialize it like this:

```
MyStruct s = {4, 5, {'a', 'b', 'c'}, "abc"};
```

You cannot initialize a `char*` with `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` because you have to provide storage for the characters, a `char*` is only able to point at something. `"abc"` happens to be a constant string literal which is stored in read only memory, so you are able to make the `char*` point at that.

Also, in C++, `"abc"` is a constant which cannot me modified, so you should change `char * secondString;` to `const char * secondString;`.

Comment: A `char*` can easily point to (the first element of) a `char` array with no terminating `'\0'`; you just need some other way to keep track of how many characters there are. Whether you can initialize it straightforwardly is another question.

Comment: Is there anyway so that I can have different sizes (in differents declarated structs) for the firstString? (I mean, any way in which i don't have to know in advance how long the array will be?)

Comment: @Trollkemada: Are you using `C` or `C++`? The answers will differ depending on that.

Comment: I'm using C (sorry aobut the mistake)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a compound literal for this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
    char * firstString;
    char * secondString;
};

struct MyStruct s = { 4, 5, (char[]){'a', 'b', 'c'}, "abc" };
```

This construct was introduced in C99; see section 6.5.2.5 of [the N1256 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). Some compilers (particularly Microsoft's) may not support it.

Note that in C, the type `struct MyStruct` cannot be referred to as just `MyStruct`; this is a difference between C and C++. Make sure you're compiling the language you think you are.

One thing to watch out for is the lifetime of the object associated with a compound literal. String literals denote array objects with static lifetime, i.e., the object exists for the entire execution of the program. The array object associated with `(char[]){'a', 'b', 'c'}` has static storage duration if it occurs outside the body of a function, but automatic storage duration (associated with the innermost enclosing block) if it occurs in side the body of the function. This could be a problem if you tried to pass a copy of `s` outside the block in which it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

A subtle point arises.  Your struct has two `char *` but has no storage to back these pointers up.  You probably want something like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
    char firstString[3];
    char secondString[4];
};
```

Comment: `"abc"` is a constant string literal which has storage, so doing `char* s = "abc"`; is legal.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MyStruct {
    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
    char * firstString;
    char * secondString;
};

int main()
{
    char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c','\0'};
    MyStruct s = {4, 5, arr, "abc"};

    cout << s.firstString << endl;

    return 0;
}

MyStruct s = {4, 5, {'a', 'b', 'c'}, "abc"};

{'a', 'b', 'c'} have no memory to store.It's a r-value.
```

——I think. ^-^